# suse install rpm package with all depends to computer that has no internet connectivity

Tags: installation, packet, rpm, wireshark, suse

Before reading, please attention, my processor is 64-bit and so my oS is Suse_10 for 64 bit.

I am trying to install wireshark on suse_10(64bit). The host does not have internet access. Therefore, I need to have all the files needed for installation; that is even the dependencies. This is to be able to install wireshark on a host with no internet connection. (Zypper, Yast would complain when no connection. It would try t go to net and find the dependencies.)

Currently, when I execute the rpm command like 'rpm -i wireshark-devel-1.2.8-2.8.x86_64.rpm', of course I get the errors that say, briefly, dependencies needed.

So, what I am looking for is the answer if I can make a "package" which has everything, and everything needed to be able to perform an flawless installation.

And of course, if the answer is yes, could you please tell me how?

I would really appreciate your help.

Or, a friend talked about "aptoncd". This works for ubuntu. This software can make the package I want, if I understood my friend correctly. But, what software can I use for "suse_10".

If I can find the software, I am thinking about to install a Suse_10 to my computer, and then using this program I would be able to make a package (that has everything needed in it).

Then, I would take this package to the host that I am trying to install wireshark on.

Can you please help?

thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "package" you are looking for is the installation DVD or its iso image.

Now "suse_10" is not how they are usually called. If you mean openSUSE 10.2 or 10.3, you can find the files via http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Mirrors#EOL_Mirrors . If you mean SUSE Linux Enterprise 10, Service Pack 3 is at http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=Z4ysu62Q4gw~